# The host and Jetson Xavier NX lose the ROS2 connection when the Ethernet LiDAR is turned on

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, network, jetson

i am currently working on a f1tenth project. The RC car has a Hokuyo 10LX Ethernet-connected LiDAR. The host and Jetson are connected through a WiFi router (DLINK DIR 600). The communication between the host and Jetson works fine as long as the LiDAR is not connected. I tested the connection multiple times using the talker and listener demo nodes. When the LiDAR is turned on, the communication between the two machines stops immediately.

The setup:

Jetson Xavier NX:
Ubuntu 20.04,
ROS2 foxy

Host:
Ubuntu 22.04,
ROS2 humble

I have tried the proposed solutions from:

https://answers.ros.org/question/404039/hokuyo-ust-10lx-connected-via-ethernet-and-urg_node/

https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1203

I have tried CycloneDDS and FastRTPS.

The connection always works when the LiDAR is turned off. Is there another way to force the communication through the WiFi interface?

**The fastrtps whitelist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<profiles xmlns="http://www.eprosima.com/XMLSchemas/fastRTPS_Profiles">
    <transport_descriptors>
        <transport_descriptor>
            <transport_id>CustomUDPTransport</transport_id>
            <type>UDPv4</type>
            <interfaceWhiteList>
                <address>192.168.0.100</address>
                <address>192.168.0.101</address>
            </interfaceWhiteList>
        </transport_descriptor>
    </transport_descriptors>
    <participant profile_name="CustomUDPTransportParticipant">
        <rtps>
            <userTransports>
                <transport_id>CustomUDPTransport</transport_id>
            </userTransports>
        </rtps>
    </participant>
</profiles>
```

**The cyclone whitelist**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
        <Domain id="any">
            <General>
                <NetworkInterfaceAddress>wifi0</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
            </General>
        </Domain>  
    </CycloneDDS>
```

Both set with `export CYCLONEDDS_URI=./whitelist_cyclonedds.xml` or `export FASTRTPS_DEFAULT_PROFILES_FILE=./whitelist_fastrtps.xml`  in the `~/.bashrc`

Thanks a lot in advance!